# How to achieve this layout using GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, jcomponent

[image]

I am confused on how to start implementing this, should I create a `GridBagLayout` with basically 4 rows and just enter the components in each?

Comment: I suggest reviewing the available layout managers. Please refer to the lesson entitled [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) which is part of Oracle's Java tutorials. There is also [JGoodies FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/) and [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

To replicate this exactly, it will be tricky, because gridBagLayout does exactly what it says... places items on a grid.

In order to get the items to display *exactly* like your image, you will need to span multiple cells and overlap them. You'll have to play around before you get it looking exactly how you want.

That being said, these are the things you should keep in mind when using GridBagLayout:

```
gbc.gridx = 0; // The x poisiton, greater value means further east
gbc.gridy = 0; // The y position, greater value means further south
```

So, If you only used 2 columns, the exit button would be:

```
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 2;
```

But, if you want it to look like the image you will have to play around with items that span multiple grids, or cells. This is how you would get some item to span an entire row.

```
gbc.gridwidth = 2; // To span 2 cells horizontally
gbc.gridheight = 2; // To span 2 cells vertically
```

You might also try using weight. For example:

```
gbc.weightx = 0.8; // Will cause the item at this cell to span 80% of the width, if there are only two columns
```

Don't forget to include your gbc when you add the item to your component, and *reset each gbc value before adding each component, even if they are the same* for readability.

Comment: To follow up, gridBagLayout grows to the number of components you add. So you don't 'initialize it' to a 4x4 like you would an array. You just tell the layout where you want items to show up, and it will adjust to you maximum x and y values.

Comment: So for example the the first Jlabel will be at 0,0 and the Jtext will be 0,1 and the calculate Jbutton will be 0,2 and Exit JButton will be 1,2 right?

Comment: Well, if you are saying (x,y), the first JLabel will be at 0,0, first Jtext at 1,0. You are correct on the position of the buttons. Once you play around with the output, you will start to have intuitions about where everything will show up. That's why I recommend setting x and y each time, even if one remains the same. It can get pretty confusing.

Comment: Cant the JLabel and the JText span the whole 0,0 row? like in the folliwng example :https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/layoutmanagers/gridbaglayout/overview

Comment: *Cant the JLabel and the JText span the whole 0,0 row?* - sure if you add them to a JPanel and add the panel as a single component. But you already stated you can only use a single GridBagLayout and nothing else. This means you can't use a JPanel which would use another layout for the two components. In any case if you used this approach you would want the buttons to be added to a panel and then add the panel as the whole 3rd row.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use two panels with `GridBagLayout` (the red outlines) and two panels with `FlowLayout` (the blue outlines).

[image]

Give it a try and get back to us if you encounter a problem.

Note that by using a GBL for the two label / field combos at the top, it would be easy to align the left hand sides of the fields, and the right hand sides of their labels (which looks better, IMO).

Comment: Thats sound very clear, but i am constrained to only use one GridBagLayout and nothing else

Comment: *"i am constrained to only use one GridBagLayout and nothing else"* That's a silly requirement. Best of luck with it, I won't spend more time on such nonsense.

Comment: *i am constrained to only use one GridBagLayout and nothing else* - then you can't solve the problem to display the components as in your picture, because in your picture your components are not being displayed in a well defined grid. Your picture shows each row of components centered within the row. This is not how a GridBagLayout